# Linking processing code to javascript while keeping the pde file separate

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, processing.js

I am working with ProcessingJs. All I want to do is get a variable from my pde file to be used in my javascript. The only example from here seems to be when you are writing the processing code directly in the javascript. I am trying to load a pde file, and then use a variable from the pde in my javascript.

Processingjs website gives these paragraphs:

> Reaching out from the Processing code to JavaScript is easier than going the other way, since the JavaScript created by the Processing.js parser is not exposed directly on the global object. Instead, you gain access using the Processing.instances property.
>
> The Processing constructor keeps track of instances it creates, and makes them available using the getInstanceById() method. By default, when a  has a data-processing-sources attribute, its id is used as a unique identifier for the Processing instance. If no id attribute is provided, you can use Processing.instances[0].

The example they point to below this paragraph has no link. This must be my answer, but I can't figure it out. Can anybody help me with this? How do I instantiate the Processing instance in my javascript?

I have tried just using getInstanceById(...) in my javascript, but it says that method is undefined in the error console.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!
~Mikeshiny

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused - I thought your .pde file basically *was* Javascript!

ANYWAY: look here:

> *
>   http://js.processing.org/reference/articles/jsQuickStart#writingpureprocessingcode
>
> **Writing Documents that Combine Processing and JavaScript Code**
>
> One of the first questions people ask with Processing.js is whether
>   they can read values from the document in which the Processing sketch
>   is running, or vice versa. The answer is yes.
>
> Processing.js converts Processing code into JavaScript contained in a
>   function closure. The variables and functions you create are not
>   attached to the global object (i.e., window). However, you can still
>   get access to them.
>
> **Accessing JavaScript Objects from Processing**
>
> Since Processing code gets converted to JavaScript and run like any
>   other function, all Processing code has access to the global object.
>   This means that if you create a variable or function in a global
>   script block, they are automatically accessible to Processing.

Comment: I am not sure this is exactly what I need though. The example here: var jsString = "Hello from JavaScript!";
var printMessage = function(msg) {
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Message: " + msg;
};

String processingString = "Hello from Processing!";

void setup() {
  printMessage(jsString + " " + processingString);
}                                                                                                    

This is kind of what I need, but I am unsure. Is the bottom half in processing and the top half in javascript? And this only shows how to a js variable in processing

Comment: Okay, so the only thing I had to do was make a global variable in the javascript and then just use that variable in my processing sketch. I did not try this before because everything was separated before, so I could still run my processing sketch in processing and it would work. Now that I have javascript variables in my processing code, it will not be able to run on its own. Now I have to upload the sketch to the web and run on there. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: im having trouble getting this to work - calling a variable from within the pde file gets an empty variable...

Answer (score 0):

For accesing *processing* from javascript you have to set an `id` to your `canvas` html element:

```
<canvas id="my-sketch" data-processing-sources="sketch.pde"></canvas>
```

And then access it using the `getInstanceById`method:

```js
var p = Processing.getInstanceById('my-sketch');
p.background(0);
p.redraw();
...
```